# Search for a specific number (in inch) where the number isn't part of a larger expression

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to use an Excel formula that returns the correct index in the cell when the text in the cell contains the term '2"' (two inch). This is possible with the `search` function.

The catch is that I only want to find instances where it's actually '2"', not cases where you have other expressions such as '1/2"' or '12"'. See the image below for an example to clarify where `search` works and where it doesn't.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a VBA solution using Regular Expressions will be easiest in order to be able to return measurements like 1 1/2".

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=FindMeasure(A1,$E$1)
```

in some cell, where E1 contains a value like 2"  or 1 1/2"

---

```
Option Explicit
Function FindMeasure(sSearch As String, ByVal sMeasure As String)
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, SM As Variant
    Dim sPat As String

sPat = "\D(\s+)" & sMeasure & "|^" & sMeasure

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat
End With

If RE.test(sSearch) = True Then
    Set MC = RE.Execute(sSearch)
    SM = MC(0).submatches(0)
    FindMeasure = MC(0).firstindex + Len(SM) + IIf(Len(SM) > 0, 2, 1)
Else
    FindMeasure = 0
End If

End Function
```

---

**EDIT:** Reviewing my answer reveals that under certain circumstances, incorrect results will be returned.

- If there is a "word" preceding the measurement which ends with a digit, the routine will fail to recognize the measurement.  This can be avoided by ensuring that there is at least one non-digit in the string preceding the measurement (by modifying the regex). However, if the entire word consists of digits, the measurement will not be recognized.
- If the line starts with a `SPACE`, the measurement will not be recognized. This can be corrected by modifying both the code and the regex to account for that possibility.
- If the cell containing the measurement, or the cell containing the string, is blank, then the result will be incorrect.  This can be avoided by testing for those conditions, by modifying the code.

**Modified Code**

---

```
Option Explicit
Function FindMeasure(sSearch As String, ByVal sMeasure As String)
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, SM As Variant
    Dim sPat As String

sPat = "(\S*\D\S*\s+)" & sMeasure & "|(^\s*)" & sMeasure

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat
End With

If RE.test(sSearch) = True And _
    Len(sSearch) > 0 And _
    Len(sMeasure) > 0 Then
    Set MC = RE.Execute(sSearch)
    SM = MC(0).submatches(0) & MC(0).submatches(1)
    FindMeasure = MC(0).firstindex + Len(SM) + 1
Else
    FindMeasure = 0
End If

End Function
```

---

Explanation of Regex with sMeasure = 2"

### (\S*\D\S*\s+)2"|(^\s*)2"

```
(\S*\D\S*\s+)2"|(^\s*)2"
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(\S*\D\S*\s+)2"`

  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\S*\D\S*\s+)`

    - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S*`

      - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
    - [Match a single character that is NOT a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\D`
    - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S*`

      - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
    - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s+`

      - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match the character string “2"” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `2"`
- [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(^\s*)2"`

  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(^\s*)`

    - [Assert position at the beginning of a line](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
    - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

      - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match the character string “2"” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `2"`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: My knowledge about VB is very poor but still want to understand mystery behind sPat = "(\S*\D\S*\s+)" & sMeasure & "|(^\s*)" & sMeasure. Surely, it is Excellent Work. It is case sensitive. If we search any alphabet except first P in Pipe 2"SCH. 40 x 43500LG, it is failed due to absence of space. However, if preceding space is present before word even then it is failed to search second or further characters of the word like i, p, e, C, H, G, why? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ZafarIqbal I don't understand your question.  If you enter 2" into E1, and your phrase into A1, and use the formula `=FindMeasure(A1,$E$1)`, the result is 6.  Isn't that what you wanted?  There is no case-sensitivity in the REGEX.

Comment: @ZafarIqbal I have added an explanation of the Regex with links to an explanatory site.

Comment: Surely searching 2" was basic question which is solved by your code. If we use this UDF for searching other than numeric then it still has some limitations. It finds correctly first single text character of word (like P in Pipe) but fails if we search next single characters (like i, p, e of same word Pipe). Any how, you did a great help. Thanks

Comment: @ZafarIqbal It was designed to search for a measurement consisting of an integer or fractional number followed by a measurement indicator such as `"`, although other measurement indicators could be used. It was very definitely **NOT** designed to search for random single characters. If you want to search for different patterns, first you will need to define that pattern, and then decide whether the best tool is a built-in VBA or Excel function; a Regular Expression; or something else.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>use:</strike>

```
=SEARCH(" 2"""," " & A1)-1
```

There are **three** tiny tricks associated with this formula:

- we search for **{space} 2 "**
- we place a blank at the start of the string
- we account for the blank by subtracting one from the position

**EDIT#1:**

This may be better.  With data in **A3** and the string in **B2** try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A3,2)=$B$2,1,SEARCH(" " & $B$2, A3)+1),0)
```

[image]

Comment: This formula is working good except for second row where 2" is at start of string, here formula is giving result Zero but it should be 1. Kindly refine this formula. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: @ZafarIqbal Copy from the formula bar and paste here the Exact formula you are using. The formula should be working

Comment: =SEARCH(" 2"""," " & A1)-1

Comment: @ZafarIqbal  Don't subtract the 1.  No need to account for the blank since we have already added a blank to A1 in doing the search. i.e. `=SEARCH(" 2"""," " & A1)`  You may note that the formula also returns 5 for A1; where it should return 6.  The formula will return the #VALUE! error if 2" not found -- wrap in IFERROR to return your `0`

Comment: Very Nice. I noticed a little more problem. If I search 1/2" in string Pipe CS, 1 1/2" NPS x SCH. 40 or string like 1 1/2" NPS x SCH. 40 x 1040 LG, result should be Zero. Please help.

Comment: Revised formula is working well. I will repeat my problem for searching 1/2" in string Pipe, CS 1 1/2" Sch. 40 or 1 1/2" Pipe Sch 80 Black. For cases like 1 1/2" at start or middle of string, result should be zero, please.

Comment: @ZafarIqbal ..........Sadly my formula does not work that way......it sees the **space 1/2"** and is happy

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right the requirements are:

1) if it starts with 2" (followed by a space)

2) there is 2" in the middle of the string (with a space on each side)

3) the string ends with 2" (preceeded by a space) it should be"OK", otherwise zero

If those are the requirements this formula should work:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,3)="2"" ",ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" 2"" ",A2)),RIGHT(A2,3)=" 2"""),"OK",0)
```

-- or you may have to use this for the second row depends on your requirements --

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,2)="2""",ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" 2"" ",A2)),RIGHT(A2,3)=" 2"""),"OK",0)
```